# Validates tinymce content length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3.1 and I have integrated a tinymce basic instance.

Now in the model I'm trying to validate the content for length and this should be > 10 let's say, but tinymce adds all sorts of html tags so this is not always relevant.

Is there some way where I can validate the data using my own function and also return the errors in the object for further manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strip_tags on your custom length validation

```
validates_length_of :text, :minimum => 10, :tokenizer => lambda { |string| strip_tags(string).split(//) }
```

see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#validates-length-of

Comment: this just didnt work for me on rails 4. nothing happened, literally.